# How can I run ripgrep using subprocess.Popen in Python3 with arguments?

Tags: python, linux, bash, popen

I use Python 3.10.7 and I am trying to get the Python interpreter to run this command:

`rg mysearchterm /home/user/stuff`

This command, when I run it in `bash` directly successfully runs `ripgrep` and searches the directory (recursively) `/home/user/stuff` for the term `mysearchterm`. However, I'm trying to do this programmatically with Python's `subprocess.Popen()` and I am running into issues:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

proc1 = Popen(["rg", "term", "/home/user/stuff", "--no-filename"],stdout=PIPE,shell=True)
proc2 = Popen(["wc","-l"],stdin=proc1.stdin,stdout=PIPE,shell=True)

#Note: I've also tried it like below:
proc1 = Popen(f"rg term /home/user/stuff --no-filename",stdout=PIPE,shell=True)
proc2 = Popen("wc -l",stdin=proc1.stdin,stdout=PIPE,shell=True)


result, _ = proc2.communicate()
print(result.decode())
```

What happens here was bizarre to me; I get an error (from `rg` itself) which says:

> error: The following required arguments were not provided:
> `<PATTERN>`

So, using my debugging/tracing skills, I looked at the process chain and I see that the python interpreter itself is performing:

```
python3          1921496 953810   0 /usr/bin/python3 ./debug_script.py
sh               1921497 1921496   0 /bin/sh -c rg term /home/user/stuff --no-filename
sh               1921498 1921496   0 /bin/sh -c wc -l
```

So my next thought is just trying to run that manually in bash, leading to the same error. However, in bash, when I run `/bin/sh -c "rg term /home/user/stuff --no-filename"` **with double quotations**, the command works in `bash` but when I try to do this programmatically in `Popen()` it again doesn't work even when I try to escape them with `\`. This time, I get errors about unexpected EOF.

Comment: To debug this, let's back up a step and try something simpler. Just call `check_run("rg term /home/user", shell=True)` and see if you can chalk up a victory there. Then go for the list form: `check_run("rg term /home/user".split())` (no shell). Then worry about connecting the pipes. [Tell us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) how it goes.

Comment: I think you should put `stdin=proc1.stdout`, even though it may not help fix the problem.

Comment: Nice catch Philippe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the behavior when `shell=True` is specified,
the [python document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) tells:

> If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself. That is to say, Popen does the equivalent of:
>
> Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])

Then your command invocation is equivalent to:

```
/bin/sh -c "rg" "term" "/home/tshiono/stackoverflow/221215" ...
```

where no arguments are fed to `rg`.

You need to pass the command as a string (not a list) *or* just drop `shell=True`.